# How to maintain equal proportion of investment after buying out a partner

Tags: arithmetic

Let's say I have five investors, each owning 20% of a company that is worth `$1,000,000`. One investor wants to be bought out. So the other investors would, to maintain their equal proportion after the buyout, each pay `$50,000` and hence would now have 25% of the company.

This makes sense to me. However, when the numbers are not equal, I am unsure how to figure out how much each person would pay.

For example, let's say:

- Investor 1 owns 50%
- Investor 2 owns 20%
- Investor 3 owns 15%
- Investor 4 owns 12%
- Investor 5 owns 3%

Investor 2 wants to sell. If the company is worth `$1,000,000`, how would one calculate how much each investor would have to pay Investor 2 to keep their proportionate share in the company?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S$ be the **sum** of the percentages controlled by the other investors. In this case, $S=0.8=80\%$.

For what Investor $1$ pays, calculate 
$$(200000)\frac{0.5}{S},$$
and similarly for the others. If you prefer, you can work with percentages. Investor $1$ pays $(200000)\frac{50}{80}$, Investor $3$ pays $(200000)\frac{15}{80}$, and so on.

So all of the quantities you calculated should be divided by $0.8$, or equivalently multiplied by $1.25$. The idea is that although your calculation gives the right *proportions*, the sum is only $160000$. To get it up to the required $200000$, you need to multiply each payment you calculated by $\frac{200000}{160000}$.